# What accounts for large execution times between simple programs in c/perl/python?

Tags: python, c, perl, execution

I wrote a simple program in C, Perl, and Python that increments a variable until it gets to 1 billion. I didn't expect there to be much difference between the different languages but was very surprised to see an enormous difference. The programs simply count to 1 billion:

In c:

```
int main() {
  int c = 0;

  while (c < 1000000000) {
    c++;
  }
}
```

In Perl:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $x = 0;

while ($x < 1000000000) {
  $x++;
}
```

And in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

i = 0
while i < 1000000000:
  i += 1
```

The run times using the zsh/bash time function is:

For c:
1.78s user 0.01s system 98% cpu 1.813 total

For perl:
29.86s user 0.13s system 99% cpu 30.205 total

And for Python:
71.96s user 0.32s system 98% cpu 1:13.16 total

It's hard for me to believe that c was 15x faster than perl and about 35x faster than Python. This seems crazy for such a simple program? Why the big difference?

Comment: First, for the C, are you sure that the compiler has not noticed that you do nothing with the value of `c`, and hence it can prune everything in `main()` ?  You could dissassemble it to find out.  If you declare the `c` as `volatile` you may see a difference -- though that will force actual memory operations, which is not entirely fair.

Comment: The fact that the C program took so long indicates that you didn't compile with optimizations enabled. With optimizations, the C program would take 0.01s user. The fact that Python is slow is due to the fact that it's an [interpreted scripting language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)), not a compiled language.

Comment: Yes, I understand python is interpreted but I'm surprised it takes 35x longer. That's shocking. And why is it twice as slow as perl, which is also interpreted?

Comment: For more information about python vs. C, google "why is python slower than c". For clues about why perl is a little faster than python, see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl#Implementation).

Comment: *"...why is it twice as slow as perl"* One way to find out is to run both scripts through [cachegrind](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html) and see how the time is spent

Comment: You can add a `asm volatile("" : "+r" (c))` inside the while loop in C to prevent the compiler from optimizing out the loop. (and compile with `-O3`) Using this, I get 0.31s for C, 32s for Perl, 99s for Python with CPython, and 0.67s with Pypy. A 100x slowdown from C to Perl on this kind of programs is consistent with other benchmarks that I've done in the past. Python being slower than Perl on the other hand depends on the application, and I would not draw any conclusion from this precise example.

Answer (score 5):

Since perl variables are untyped (and can in fact change their effective type during the course of execution), every operation on them (such as < and ++) has to check: is this a tied variable; is this an overloaded value; is this an integer; or a float; or a string: and if so does it have a valid numeric interpretation; or is it undef? Etc etc. For binary ops like <, that logic applies to both args, and the types of the args can differ. So perl has to handle ints added to floats etc.

Also, perl doesn't restrict the result of arithmetic ops to be an int. Instead it dymamically updates the type of the variable, e.g. from signed int to unsigned int to double, to best preserve the value and accuracy of the result.

This means that perl has to do a huge amount of work for e.g. a simple addition: compared with C, where the compiler knows that both args are signed integers and doesn't care if the result overflows; and can map the addition to a single CPU addition instruction

Comment: That makes sense. Just didn't realize it would be such a huge disparity for a simple operation. And what about the difference between perl and python?

Comment: The observations on dynamic variable typing apply to Python as well (though that does not explain why perl is faster).

Comment: @StevieD, Honestly, one thing taking twice the time of another isn't particularly interesting. It's when the hot parts of your program take twice as long that it starts getting interesting. Wild guess: Maybe the Python code requires dynamic memory allocation? The Perl one doesn't. (I know nothing of Python internals. Perl will simply use a pointer to the scalar containing `1` rather than making a new scalar, and `$x++` is optimized to `++$x` which modifies `$x` in-place without needing to allocate a temporary scalar to hold the original value of `$x`.)